# create a unique number using Rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I need to create a random number each time a page is loaded. I have a view page like below.

**index.html.erb**:

```
<th style="width: 30%; text-align:left; vertical-align: top;">Date: <%= Date.today.to_s %><br />
                    Bill No.: </th>
```

In this file, I want to create a new unique bill number each time the page is loaded. Please help me resolve this error.

Comment: @sawa I don't believe there is an error... Rajat wants to know which function in ruby can generate a random number to place after `Bill No.:` such as: `Bill No.: <% 1 + rand(6) %>`

Comment: This seems like an odd way to generate a "Bill Number" since this seems like a reference point and would be useless if it is constantly changing, not to mention a little disconcerting for the end user.

Answer (score 0):

```
<th style="width: 30%; text-align:left; vertical-align: top;">Date: <%= Date.today.to_s %><br />
                Bill No.: <%= rand(10000) %></th>
```

Answer (score 0):

@letz's answer helps you generate a random number on the view. But each time when the page is loaded, the number will change.

It is not a good practice. So, it's better to save the random number in the database and display it in the view